# Adding mode to my monitor doesn't work in Xubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xubuntu

I'm trying to add new resolutions to my monitor. I installed NVIDIA driver via `ubuntu-drivers`. 
My graphics card is GeForce GTX 1660 Ti. The only available resolution is 1920x1080 which looks pretty good on my laptop, but the problem is that the writing is a bit small. So I would like to decrease a bit the resolution (in order to increase the icons, text, etc). When I run:

```
xrandr
```

I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If I try to add a new mode:

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_144.00"  280.00  1440 1560 1712 1984  900 903 909 981 -hsync +vsync
```

it gets added to a different output:

```
xrandr
```

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1440x900_144.00 (0x255) 280.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1560 end 1712 total 1984 skew    0 clock 141.13KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  981           clock 143.86Hz
```

And finally, If I try to add this mode to the connected output:

```
xrandr --output DP-4 --mode "1440x900_144.00"
```

I get:

```
xrandr: cannot find mode 1440x900_144.00
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Could I suggest a different approach? Install `arandr` and use its GUI interface. (I think it is just a GUI front end to `xrandr`) I have an NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti and 1440x900 is one of the optional resolutions `arandr` offers.

Comment: @OrganicMarble No difference. You already stated that arandr uses xrandr. :). I tried and the same problem.